# matching words containing repeating characters

Tags: java, regex

This is my regex: `"(?<=^|\\s)([a-z])\\1{3,}(?=\\s|$)"`.

I am trying to match words that have repeating characters > 2 in a row.

So `wwhhaaaat bananas ffffuuuuuu this is a test` should catch `wwhhaaaat` and `ffffuuuuuu`.

When I run this regex in java it is not catching anything. When I run `([a-z])\\1{3,}` it catches the repeating characters only. SO I am messing up the part to match the word containing the characters.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[a-z]*([a-z])\\1{3,}[a-z]*").matcher("So wwhhaaaat bananas ffffuuuuuu this is a test");
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

prints

```
wwhhaaaat
ffffuuuuuu
```

Comment: Hey that works. Can you explain the `[a-z]*`. I thought I had to do a look ahead to match the whole word. How does `[a-z]*` do it? Isn't that like any letter?

Comment: Seems logical: any number of letters (0 or more) followed by repeated 3 (or more) letters followed by any number of letters. BTW i suggest \\w